# Rails 3 and Devise. Kill current session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got an Rails 3 app that uses Devise. I am just wondering how I can "kill" the current session?

This works but I do not know what it does

```
Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
```

This does not work

```
current_user = nil
```

This does not work either

```
session[:current_user] = nil
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want the sign_out method, and pass either the user or scope (eg `:user`) that you want to sign out.

Check out the [Devise Ruby Doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/TestHelpers:sign_out) for more information.

Comment: The first one work but I am worried that I will logout ALL logged in users.

Comment: If you just pass a single user object to `sign_out` it should only sign out that one.

Comment: To clarify, I wouldn't use the whole first line you posted, just `sign_out(current_user)`

Comment: Like this? sign_out current_user

Comment: Yep, that should do it. Of course, you should do some tests to make sure. Using two browsers should let you log in as two different users, and then you can try the log out with one and see if it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but sign_out(current_user) does nothing.
What am I doing wrong? Also not even the first option works "Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)"

Answer (score 21):

you can do like this

```
sign_out current_user
```

or

```
sign_out :user     # sign_out(scope)
```

or

```
sign_out @user     # sign_out(resource)
```