# Automatically signout a user if account is not enabled (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to automatically sign out a user if his account is not enabled.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <% if current_user.enabled == "no" %>
   <% flash.alert = "Your account is disabled! Please contact support for more information" %>
   <% sign_out current_user %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I get a "undefined method `sign_out' for #<#:0x007f92001bce68>" error. I am using devise. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should do it in controller.

Comment: @MarekLipka I will "do it" in controller after making it work. First make it work, then refactor.

Comment: You are right about red, green, refactor however you should still keep the MVC architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set your enabled attribute to a boolean type.

In your ApplicationController

```
before_filter :check_user

def check_user
  sign_out current_user if current_user && current_user.disabled?
end
```

In your User model:

```
def disabled?
  enabled == false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in devise with this name and update it according to your requirements

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
        super
        session[:id] = current_user.id
        session[:enable] = current_user.email
        if current_user.enabled = "no"
          flash.alert = "Your account is disabled! Please contact support for more information"          
          sign_out_path
        else
         flash.alert = "Successfully login."
         redirect_to "specify your path for redirect"
       end
  end
```

Comment: thanks but not exactly what I am looking for. I want to immediately signout the user, not just after sign_in.

Comment: i am after something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6315624 but it doesn't work on Rails4(?) or my case... as i tried it.

Comment: ok then write a method in before filter the check that user is enable or not.

Comment: @Stefanos.Ioannou you should check it where the session is created, devise gives the permission you to overwrite methods.